# Presenting walkthrough in iOS app

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

I am pushing out version 2 of my app and need a short walkthrough of the new features. I went through a tutorial and created my walkthrough in another app, with one UIViewController that is root view, a UIPageViewController which contains one UIView where I display my screens. It works as I want it.

Now I want to integrate this in my app. I can easily import my coding from the sample app.

I believe in the app delegate I will see if the user has ever been through the walkthrough, and if not, switch to the UIViewController that starts the walkthrough, and write to a default that the user has seen the walkthrough (so they don't need to see it again). I have a button in the walkthrough to go the main screen.

My partial code for the method "applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions is below:

```
                - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard.storyboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *walkthrough = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextViewController"];
        //[self presentViewController:walkthrough animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.window setRootViewController:walkthrough];

        return YES;
    }
```

Here is the completed code that works. Thanks very much for the help:

```
      // User Defaults
      UserDefaults *thisUserDefaults = [[UserDefaults alloc] init];
      [thisUserDefaults registerDefaults];

      if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
              valueForKey:kAppHasRunBeforeKey] boolValue]) {

        UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *walkthrough =
            [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:walkthrough];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES
                                                forKey:kAppHasRunBeforeKey];
      }
```

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Comment: Karan, thank you so much. This looks excellent!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best and easiest possible method to show tips would be to use this library:
https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView

Otherwise, if you want to do it with the approach you mentioned then you will need to keep a variable in `NSUserDefaults` lets say a bool `walkthroughShownOnce`. Initially if you are accessing the variable in the app delegate from NSUserDefaults like this:

```
bool tempInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"walkthroughShownOnce"];
```

then it will return `false`. This is when you show your walkthrough and in the end after you have shown the walk through, simply make the variable true like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"walkthroughShownOnce"];
```

Comment: That is great. But I am really struggling with 2 things. One, where to put the code, in the app delegate or the root view controller. Two, how do I programatically switch to viewController that starts the walkthrough and then back to the original view controller?

Comment: Place the NSUserDefaults code write above the following line in your applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:
`UIStoryboard *storyBoard;`

Your code would look like this:
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"walkthroughShownOnce"]==true)
{
//here are the four lines you have written from `UIStoryboard *storyBoard;` onwards
}
else
{
//Here you open your other view controller that gets opened now
//If it gets automatically opened without writing the code in AppDelegate then you don't need this else statement
}

Comment: Then in your walkthrough controller, once you have shown the walkthrough completely, call you first view controller

Comment: Thanks Khawari, I used your code and figured out one of my problems, that my storyboard id was incorrect. I now have this working perfectly. Up voted and checked as correct.

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 2):

There's this library too [SwiftyWalkthrough](https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough).